# :target pseudo selector not selecting target

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

Forgive me if somebody has posted about the same problem, I was unable to find a similar issue with an answer.

When I click on my button with the #dotNetComponents url it takes me to the div with the dotNetComponents ID but goes a little too far, cutting off the header and some of the text. I believe the reason is because of my sticky header, but I am not 100% sure of this. Anyway, I need to add a buffer to the top of the target so none of the div is cut off. After searching around, I found the css below, it seems like it should be working right. When I changed the css from :target to :hover, I was able to see the page actively making changes upon my hover over the div with the ID. Therefore, the problem lies within the :target selector itself. Please help.

Here is a simplified version of my html:

```
<a href="#dotNetComponents" class="btn transformBtn">.NET COMPONENTS</a>

<div id="dotNetComponents" class="interiorContent container offsetAnchor">
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
 #dotNetComponents:target::before { 
   display: block; 
   content: " "; 
   margin-top: -110px;
   height: 110px; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   pointer-events: none;
 }
```

Comment: It's looking and seems to be [working](https://jsfiddle.net/3x4wk2pq/1/) fine, you might have something else interfering.

Answer (score 0):

## CSS Scrolling

If you are using a link just to navigate within the page `:target` isn't needed nor is `::before`.
**In the following demo:**

- A block element is wrapped around the target element (ex. `<article>`)
- The previously mentioned element has these required properties:

A common problem when scrolling from a link is that the target element might be too close to the link -- note that the target elements have a 100vh `margin-top/bottom`. The size of the margins are up to you, but I recommend a margin that pushes the target off screen. Also, if the target element is at the bottom of a page, it will scroll up only as far as it's `margin-bottom` or the parent element `padding-bottom`.

---

> ```
> overflow-y: scroll; /* Adds a persistent vertical scrollbar */
> scroll-behavior: smooth; /* Animates scrolling */
> height: 150px; /* This varies as long as it's a fixed height. */
> ```

---

### Demo

```css
nav a {
  font-size: 15vh;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center
}

article {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 150px;
}

section {
  margin: 100vh auto;
  height: 110px;
  line-height: 110px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  font-size: 15vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#A">A</a>

  <a href="#B">B</a>

  <a href="#C">C</a>
</nav>
<article>
  <section id="A">A</section>
  <section id="B">B</section>
  <section id="C">C</section>
</article>
```